# Prevent Bootstrap collapse item from "jumping"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've set up a Bootstrap collapse plugin to use with my list of frequently asked questions:

https://jsfiddle.net/2d8ytuq0/

```
<ul class="faq__questions">
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq__question_1">..</a>
    <p class="collapse" id="faq__question_1">...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is when you collapse back the extended description it kind of "jumps". I think this happens due to the bottom margin the `p` element has. I tried to replace it with `padding-bottom`, but this didn't solve the issue. Is there any way to fix this without breaking the original layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem causes because your collapsed element has a `margin-bottom:15px`.

**Your new HTML markup**

```html
<div class="collapse" id="faq__question_1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nesciunt rerum mollitia nobis corporis sint error quaerat cupiditate animi doloribus! Voluptas dolores, incidunt perspiciatis labore velit libero minus consequuntur blanditiis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I DO need this margin, otherwise its content would be too close to the border.

Comment: Ok, then create a wrapper `div`. See updated answer.

Comment: This makes sense then. This requires additional markup though, but might be the only solution.

Comment: Yes, I know. I had ever this problem too. This the only solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this css to override margin property..This works fine

```
.faq__questions > li p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a css transition to it.

I add an active state to the panels and to a css transition on the `margin-top`.

**JS**

```
// Add active class to open panel on faqs accordion
$('.faq__questions').on('show.bs.collapse', 'li', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.faq__questions').on('hide.bs.collapse', 'li', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.faq__questions li .collapse{
    margin-top: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.faq__questions li.active .collapse{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```